# I am trying to animate an object with css in react and change the animation (timing) dynamically, how can I set the style after animation end?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I am trying to make a hot air balloon styled button that floats (translates over x and y space). Currently I am using CSS variable to set animation properties but I can only do this once or else I get an error saying 
"TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '--animation-time' of object '#'" 
How do I work around this to be able to set new random properties for where the animation starts, ends, and how long it lasts?
Currently I have this:

```
class HotAir extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){  
    super(props);  
    this.state = {
      link: props.link,
      cls: props.cls,
      img: props.img,
      text: props.text,
    }  
  }  

  render(){
    var cssProperties = {};
    cssProperties['--animation-time'] = Math.random()*10 + 's';
    console.log(cssProperties);

    
    return(
      <div className="balloon" style={cssProperties} onAnimationEnd={()=> cssProperties['--animation-time'] = '60s'}>
        <Link to={this.state.link}><button className="balloonbutt">
          <img src={this.state.img} alt=""></img>
          <div className="balloontext">{this.state.text}</div></button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my relevant css

```
.balloon{
    --animation-time: 60s;
    --x-float-start: 10vw;
    --y-float-start: 10vh;
    --x-float-end: 20vw;
    --y-float-end: 20vh;
    position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
    animation: float var(--animation-time) linear;
}
@keyframes float{
    0%{
        left: var(--x-float-start);
        top: var(--y-float-start);
    }
    100%{
        left: var(--x-float-end);
        top: var(--y-float-end);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and got no issues on https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pemaug

Comment: One advice, don't use var. Use const or let instead. It must be something to do with your code linting set up I assume.

Comment: @SanishJoseph yea that works the problem occurs when i try to set it again after the animation is complete

Comment: I think you should move your variable to state obejct and handle it as in my answer. Let me know if you still get error.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code in more Reacty way. You were using a var object and mutating the data which is not how React expects things to be done. I have updated my code and hopefully your linting tool won't complain after the changes.

Changes:

1. Added `cssProperties` to state so react will be aware of that property.
2. Instead of mutating the value on animation end, updated the state with,

> this.setState({
> ...this.state,
> cssProperties: { '--animation-time': '60' }
> });

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

interface AppProps {}
interface AppState {
  name: string;
  cssProperties;
}

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      cssProperties: {
    '--animation-time': Math.random() * 10 + 's',
    '--x-float-start': Math.trunc(Math.random() * 200) - 10 + 'px',
    '--y-float-start': Math.trunc(Math.random() * 200) - 10 + 'px',
    '--x-float-end': Math.trunc(Math.random() * 200) - 10 + 'px',
    '--y-float-end': Math.trunc(Math.random() * 200) - 10 + 'px'
  }
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.cssProperties);
    return (
      <div
        className="balloon"
        style={this.state.cssProperties}
        onAnimationIteration={() => {
          console.log(this.state.cssProperties);
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        cssProperties: {
          ...this.state.cssProperties,
          '--x-float-start': this.state.cssProperties['--x-float-end'],
          '--y-float-start': this.state.cssProperties['--y-float-end'],
          '--x-float-end': Math.trunc(Math.random() * 200) - 10 + 'px',
          '--y-float-end': Math.trunc(Math.random() * 200) - 10 + 'px'
        }
      });
          
        }}
      >
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Update**

Since you need an infinite animation, your CSS should have that option.

```
 animation: float var(--animation-time) linear infinite;
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! However now it is stops being animated after the animation set from the onAnimationEnd method. is there any way to call that repeatedly? Ideally it would infinitely select a new location after each animation?

Comment: You mean you need a new value every time after the animations? Keep your random value generator instead of fixing 60 may be.

Comment: yes, I had just used 60 in my example to see if i could set it at all. I have changed the onAnimationEnd function to the following `this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          cssProperties: { '--animation-time': '10s', 
          '--x-float-start': this.state.cssProperties['--x-float-end'],
          '--y-float-start': this.state.cssProperties['--y-float-end'],
          '--x-float-end': Math.trunc(Math.random()*200) - 10 + 'px',
          '--y-float-end': Math.trunc(Math.random()*200) - 10 + 'px'}
        });
      }`
but my problem now is it only animates twice

Comment: Check my update. You need to have a infinite animation in that case.

Comment: Now the onAnimationEnd function doesnt run because the animation is infinite/never ends. to be clear I want it to change destinations each time the animation ends and then start going to the new destination.

Comment: Use `onAnimationIteration` instead of `onAnimationEnd`. I have updated my code.

Comment: My example code works as you need I suppose, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pemaug?file=style.css